# Sharing resources(files, mutexes) between threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm writing a C++ class, that controls serial port (RS232) on GNU/Linux and I have decided (based on number of articles concerning Async I/O on Linux) to use multiple threads in which blocking read/write functions will be used.

I do wonder, how to correctly share certain resources: file descriptor of the serial port and mutexes. All examples I have found so far create FD and Mutexes as global variables, which ensures, that they will be shared into any new thread created.

However since I am creating a class and want to have a FD and Mutexes as Private variables, this is not really an option for me.

1) File descriptor:

Will simply sharing FD in `void * arg` for `pthread_create` suffice or is it better to open the serial port in each thread? Perhaps a third option?

2) Mutexes:

Will simply sharing Mutex address in `void * arg` for `pthread_create` suffice or do I need to create a shared memory segment as if I was using semaphores and shared them among multiple processes?

I know that the question is not asked very well and I appologise in advance.

Also thank you for your help.

EDIT:

The code I keep seeing on the net is something like this:

```
/* Global variables */
pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int file_descriptor = 0;

struct my_data_t
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int id;
};

void * thread_routine(void *aData_)
{
    my_data_t * data = (my_data_t*) aData_;
    int err = 0; 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

    err = read(file_descriptor, data->buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
    /* executes thread routine */
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t new_thread;
    pthread_attr_t new_thread_info;
    my_data_t thread_data;
    thread_data.id = 1;
    /* setting up thread */

    file_descriptor = open(DEVICE_NAME, O_RDWR );
    pthread_mutex_init(&thread_mutex, NULL);

    pthread_create(&new_thread, &new_thread_info, &thread_routine, (void*) &thread_data);

    pthread_join(new_thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Both File Descriptor and Mutex are created as Global Variables and are therefore available in the new thread. What I need is a way to share these resources with the new thread, when they are enclosed in a C++ class like this:

```
class Example
{
private:
    pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    int file_descriptor = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
public:
    Example(/* args */);
    ~Example();
    ...
};
```

The possibilities I have come up with are passing a pointer to the original file descriptor and mutex via the `void * agr`argument in `pthread_create()` in a structure like this:

```
struct data_for_thread_t
{
    char **buffer;
    int * p_file_descriptor;
    pthread_mutex_t * p_thread_mutex; 
};
```

Or to open the required file in the new thread and instead of using pthread_mutex I would use classic POSIX semaphore and share it via `shm`.

Comment: Use `std::thread` not the low-level pthreads APIs.

Comment: What are the advantages?

Comment: `std::thread` is a C++ API. C++ APIs are often superior to C APIs because of increased type safety, increased run-time safety, and increased optimisation opportunities. There are exceptions but this is not one of them.

Comment: Re, "...global variables, which ensures, that they will be copied into any new thread..." No. There's no "copying" when a thread accesses a global variable. Remember, every program you've ever written has been "threaded." It's just that most of them up until now have only ever had one thread. When the second or third or nth thread of your program accesses a global variable, it doesn't happen any differently from when the main (first) thread in your program accesses the global variable.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sorry for that. But do I understand it correctly, that global variables are placed Data Segment which is shared among threads, but variables of the main function are in Stack and therefore are not shared?

Comment: I'm having problems understanding your description of where you encountered an obstacle. What have you tried, what where the problems you found? Please restrict yourself to one problem per question and try to provide a [mcve] with it. Also, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am trying to understand how to correctly share resources between threads. I have edited the question to  better explain what am I looking for. Also I am currently looking into `std::threads` but I am still interested in the answer

Comment: @RadekHlavinka Stacks are shared. While each thread has its own stack, each thread's own stack is also 100% shared with every other thread. (My wife and I each have our own car. However, she can use my car as easily as hers and I can use her car as easily as mine. The two of us cooperate to get optimal use out of both cars.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a shot at explaining why the code you've found online is structured the way it is: The most probable reason is that the author doesn't have enough skills and experience. Sounds harsh, but I'm afraid that I can even provide good arguments for that opinion. Now, for the reasons...

Firstly, to clarify a point, a thread is a "point of control" or an "independent execution". It "lives" in a process, with possible other threads. Within that process, it shares a memory space with all other threads in that process. That means that there is no memory exclusively accessible by just one of the threads! This means that you can access a local variable of one thread from another thread. However, the other thread typically doesn't know the location of those variable, so it practically can't. Keeping that info separated helps, because you don't want to accidentally mess with things that are some other thread's. However, there's no need to make things global in order to make them accessible. You can work with local variables who's address you pass along.

Now, in some cases, you want to share information between threads. Comparing that to a function, if you want to access some data there, you basically have two ways: One way is to pass the data as parameter to the function, the other is store the data as global. Now, threads are not much different from functions, only that the function invoked via `pthread_create()` only takes a void pointer. `std::thread` is much more flexible than that, you can easily pass multiple different parameters in a type-safe way. However, global variables still remain as option.

Why is the mentioned code bad? The point is that it uses a mixture between global variables (mutex, filedescriptor) and arguments (my_data_t) and that for no reason. A much more sane approach would be either make all of them global or pass all of them as parameter. Prefer the latter, it makes code easier to test in isolation. For an explanation of why the mixture is particularly bad, see below.

Further, it is bad because it doesn't demonstrate anything. It shows a thread being started for no reason and the thread performing useless operations (mutex lock, mutex unlock). The mutex is completely useless, because no other code ever touches the filedescriptor or the buffer while the thread is running! Since no other code touches the data, it isn't shared and it doesn't need its access synchronized with a mutex. Waiting for the thread to complete is enough synchronization here.

However, let's assume that you have some shared data that is concurrently accessed by multiple threads. In order to get this right, you synchronize access via a mutex. Since nothing really prevents you from accessing data without locking the mutex, mistakes happen easily. A strategy for avoiding mistakes is to make it obvious that this data is shared between threads. Further, make it obvious which mutex is responsible for protecting this data. There are two common ways to achieve that. The first way is to simply wrap the data and the mutex in a struct, so that it's obvious they belong together. The second way is document this with a simple comment. This also forces you to make a plan in your head, which is a good thing. In particular, it is then unlikely that you share data but don't have a mutex or that you have two of them! Neither of these two very simple strategies has been employed by the author of the code you have found online, which is another argument against it.

Lastly, the example code ignores that you can also return something from a thread, just as you return something from a function. This can be retrieved via the second argument to `pthread_join()`. Using `std::thread`, you get even more options. If the example code had used that feature, it could have returned the buffer filled with the data from the file. The synchronization is then only performed by the call to `pthread_join()`.

Notes:

- Note that in C++ you can also have a non-global variable in a namespace or as a static variable inside a class, but that's similar to being global for the question at hand.
- Other than mutexes, there are also atomic operations that can sometimes be used as alternative to mutexes. Keep that in mind as another thing to learn.
- Avoid threads that compete for a resource. If they do, they tend to take turns at blocking the other's progress, so you neither get the benefit of independent execution nor that of speedup from parallel execution. Prefer threads that cooperate instead.
- If you can, avoid sharing of data. Prefer exclusive ownership instead. You can set up a task and give it to a thread for execution. When finished, the thread gives you the result. In particular `std::unique_ptr` lends itself to this strategy. Since the data is not shared but passed on, it doesn't require any access synchronization and the overhead it implies. This is also more of a cooperation as mentioned above.
- C++ allows you do lots of clever stuff. For example, you can wrap a datastructure and a mutex and only allow access with the mutex locked. Check out smart pointer implementations and their `operator->` overload for inspiration.
- The class you sketched had constructor and destructor, but don't forget to delete copy constructor and assignment operator. Check out the "Law of Three".
- Your approach with `struct data_for_thread_t` was close, you only need to drop that indirection with the pointers. In general, avoid pointers in C++.
- As a suggestion, try to implement the example (reading a file in the background) properly. When you have it working, submit the code for a review at codereview.stackexchange.com. Do checkout their guidelines first though, as they differ substantially from those of Stack Overflow.